# NSDateIntervalFormatter android counterpart?

Tags: android, internationalization

Any one known how to format a date range with respect to different language and locale setting in android? like `NSDateIntervalFormatter` in iOS do?

Comment: What do you mean by "i18nly"?

Comment: @iRuth i18n refers to [internationalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization#Naming).

Answer (score 0):

See formatDateRange in android.text.format.DateUtils
(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html)